# Select the implementation of the parent class at runtime

Tags: c++, inheritance, runtime, c++14

In a fairly large project, I have a `Parent1` class, which is inherited by several derived classes. I need to add a new implementation for an alternative implementation of the parent class. The selection of whether to use `Parent1` or `Parent2` will be done at runtime.

A minimal example would be as below.

**current setup**

```
class Parent1 {
    void doParentStuff() {
        std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : Parent1 {
     void doChildStuff() {
          doParentStuff();
     }
};
```

**Desired setup**

Now I want to add a new file, that contains the implementation of `Parent2`, which would look like this:

```
class Parent2 {
    void doParentStuff() {
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Maybe I create a new `Parent` class, that is the base class of both `Parent1` and `Parent2`

and ideally the Derived class would now look like this:

```
class Derived : Parent {
     Derived( bool whichParent ) {
         // decide here whether to inherit from Parent1 or Parent2
     }
     void doChildStuff() {
          doParentStuff(); // this will print 0 or 1, with the choice made at runtime
     }
}
```

An obviously clean solution would be to change the design from inheritance to composition. However, I am trying to make this work in the shortest amount of time, with the less extra code possible, while keeping the inheritance structure. Is that even possible?

Comment: Cannot be done at runtime, `template <typename Base> struct D : Base {/*..*/};` is possible though.

Comment: No, it's not possible, sorry. C++ does not work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done.

You can, however, try something like this:

```
class SuperParent { ... };

class Parent1 : public SuperParent { ... };
class Parent2 : public SuperParent { ... };

template<class Base>
class Derived : public Base { ... };

SuperParent * derivedFactory(bool which) {
    if (which) {
        return new Derived<Parent1>();
    } else {
        return new Derived<Parent2>();
    }
}
```

if the resulting inheritance hierarchy allows for the functionality you need.

Comment: Prefer to return `std::unique_ptr<SuperParent>` instead of raw owning pointer.